# "Exception: All images must be able to be 'zoomed in' to the largest image." when using pyrtools library

Tags: python, image, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I am trying to use the pyrtools library in Python to filter some images using Steerable Pyramids. My images have a dimension of 365*568. When I use the function "display" from the library, I get the Exception: All images must be able to be 'zoomed in' to the largest image.That is, the largest image must be a scalar multiple of all images.

For now, I have tried cutting my images to a dimension of 256*256. My question is if I can use the function "display" with the original dimension of my images, and if so how. Also, if it is not possible to use the function with rectangular images, which is the biggest dimension of a square image I can use?